# Raspberry pi OS get audio output from both ui and mpd?

Tags: audio, mpd

I'm running ui with XFCE on `a Raspberry pi OS Linux 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux`, I can hear audio from audio jack starting applications from the ui (i.e. open browser ) and control volume via upper right task bar icon.

If I stop the ui and start mpd configured with alsa output it works.
If I start mpd while ui is running it complains `ERROR: Failed to open "RPiCirrus" (alsa);Failed to open ALSA device; Device or resource busy`.

Is there a way to share the device between ui and mpd?

Comment: If you are running a 64 bit OS you are NOT using "rasbpian"(sic).

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two components involved:

- system level **ALSA**
- user ui use **pulseaudio**

So should share pulseadio by adding to **etc/pulse/default.pa**:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1
```

then in **/etc/mpd.conf**:

```
audio_output {
       type     "pulse"
       name     "My PULSE Device"
       server   "127.0.0.1"
}
```